# Angular 11 & ngbPopover - Changing autoClose mode on clicking a button inside the popover

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the ngbPopover along with angular 11 to show a popup for which the behavior has to be changed on the fly.

The default autoClose behavior of the popup should be 'outside', which means that any outside click on the popup will close it.

However, when the user clicks a button inside the popup, it will 'transform' and the user can only now close it by clicking on an update button inside it.

Can anyone advise on how this can be done? Below is my trigger code for your reference. I have tried to change the autoClose property on the popover instance but to no avail.

```
<div container="body" triggers="manual" #existingCommentPopover="ngbPopover"
                            *ngIf="isExistingCommentShown(element)"
                            (mouseenter)="editExistingComment(element, existingCommentPopover)"
                            class="comment-triangle existing-comment-triangle" 
                            placement="top [autoClose]="'outside'"
                            [ngbPopover]="existingCommentsContent" [popoverClass]="'new-comment-popup'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to work around this unfortunately.

I ended up setting 'autoClose' to false and attaching a click event to the body and closing the popover if the popup was in its initial mode and bypassing it after it transforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some custom flag to check if the user has clicked the button or not. And you can then use that to determine the input for the `[autoClose]`.

```
[autoClose]="buttom_clicked?'inside':'outside'"
```

Comment: Thank you . I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: I am sorry. This doesn't seem to work once the popup is opened. I am able to change the autoClose property through code before the instance is opened, After that, it does not work.